# Geometry problem about angles and triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've been working on this problem for a while. It doesn't seem to hard, but I cannot reach a satisfying solution.

> The triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with base $\overline{AC}$. A point $O$ is also given.
>
> Knowing: $\overline{OA}=R$, $\overline{AB}\equiv \overline{BC}=r$ and the angles $\widehat{OAB}=\varphi$, $\widehat{AOC}=\theta$, find the values of $\overline{OC}$ and $\widehat{OCB}$.

[image: Blue objects are known, red are not]Blue objects are known, red are not.

Original (equivalent but messier) formulation:

> On the plane $\pi$, two half lines: $s$, $t$ start from a point $O$ forming an angle $\theta$ between them.
>
> A point $A$ is given on the line $s$ and a point $B$ is given on the plane $\pi$ such that $\overline{AB} >\text{dist}(B,t)$.
>
> Find the biggest $\overline{OC}$ such that $\overline{AB}\equiv\overline{BC}$ with $C$ lying on the line $t$. What are the values of the segment $\overline{OC}$ and of the angle $\widehat{OCB}$?

So far I've been able to get:

$\widehat{CBA}=\widehat{AOC}+\widehat{OAB}+\widehat{OCB}$

which still contains two unknowns. I should have worked out a complete system of equations using triangles sine and cosine formulas, but then the substitutions become messy and I cannot reach anything as simple as the problem seems. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: I don't understand something. The point $C$ lies on the circle about $B$ of radius $AB$. It also lies on the line $T$ containing the half-line $t$. The intersections of a line and a circle are straightforward to compute; the only problem here is that one of the intersection might be "on the wrong side of $O$", so to speak. But if you parameterize the ray $t$ as the set of points $O + uv$, where $v$ is a vector and $u$ is nonnegative, you just solve the quadratic in $u$ and take the larger root. Am I missing something? Do I have to use just Euclid, or are coordinates allowed?

Comment: @John I don't think you are missing anything. If you have only one intersection with the half line, then that is the one to take. Since it is not an homework, the solution could go through any procedure, the important point is to get the functions to compute the unknowns from the given things.

Comment: @John Where would you apply Euclid's Theorem? I do not see any significant 90° angle in the picture...

Comment: When I said "Euclid", I meant "Euclid's postulates, and the usual stuff from geometry class" as opposed to things like coordinates. (I think perhaps you mis-remembered Pythagoras as Euclid in your comment, or maybe there's a Euclid's Theorem that I don't know). Anyhow, I'll give a detailed answer a bit later.

Comment: @John Sorry, however there are actually two Euclid's Theorems, at least so they are called in Italy: 1. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/c/c2/Primo_teorema_di_Euclide.svg 2. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/3/31/Secondo_teorema_di_Euclide.svg

Comment: Thanks for the pointers -- very cool!

Comment: @DarioP I try to solve it in trigonometric way - a slight deviation from Euclid, but at least is non-coordinates. See the answer outlined below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take as starting data the following, using your first formulation of things. 
\begin{align}
\newcommand{\uvec}{{\bf u}}
\newcommand{\wvec}{{\bf w}}
P &= (x, y), \text{the coordinates of your point $O$, which I'll call $P$}\\
B &= (s, t), \text{the coordinates of $B$}\\
A &= (a, b), \text{the coordinates of $A$}\\
\uvec &= (h, k), \text{a vector pointing from $P$ towards $C$}
\end{align}

Thus points on the ray you called $t$ are all of the form 
$$
P + c \uvec
$$
for some nonnegative number $c$.

Let
\begin{align}
r &= \sqrt{(s-a)^2 + (t-b)^2}, \text{the distance from $A$ to $B$}
\end{align}
For any value of $c$, we know that the vector from $P + c \uvec$ to $B$ is 
\begin{align}
{\bf w} &= P + c\uvec - B \\
&= c \uvec + (P-B) \\
&= c (h, k) + (x-s, y-t) \\
&= (ch + x-s, ck + y - t). 
\end{align}
We'd like to pick $c$ so that the length of $\wvec$ is exactly $r$, or, equivalently, so that its squared length is $r^2$. That means solving
\begin{align}
(ch + x-s)^2 + (ck + y - t)^2 = r^2 
\end{align}
Expanding out the left-hand side, we get
\begin{align}
c^2h^2 + 2ch(x-s)+ (x-s)^2 + c^2k^2 + 2ck(y - t) + (y-t)^2 &= r^2\\ 
c^2(h^2 + k^2) + c\left(2h(x-s) + 2k(y - t) \right) + (x-s)^2 + (y-t)^2 - r^2 &= 0. 
\end{align}

That's a quadratic expression in $c$, whose roots are
\begin{align}
c &= \frac{1}{2(h^2 + k^2)}\left(-\left(2h(x-s) + 2k(y - t) \right) \pm \sqrt{\left(2h(x-s) + 2k(y - t) \right)^2 - 4(h^2 + k^2)((x-s)^2 + (y-t)^2 - r^2)}\right) 
\end{align}
The larger of these two roots finds the point farther along the ray from $P$; that larger root is 
\begin{align}
c &= \frac{1}{2(h^2 + k^2)}\left(-\left(2h(x-s) + 2k(y - t) \right) + \sqrt{\left(2h(x-s) + 2k(y - t) \right)^2 - 4(h^2 + k^2)((x-s)^2 + (y-t)^2 - r^2)}\right) 
\end{align}
and the resulting point, $C$, is at the location
$$
(x_c, y_c) = (x + ch, y + ck)
$$
where $c$ is the expression given above.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the figure below, 
(1) my ‘Ø’ is the same as your ‘φ’; (2) O and B are joined; (3) let OC cut AB at D.
[image]

Let p, q, s, t be the names of some functions.

In ⊿OAB, OB = p(R, r, Ø) ---- [cosine law] ---&--- x = q(R, OB, Ø) ---- [sine law]

In ⊿OBD, y = θ + Ø ---- [ext. < of ⊿] ---&--- z = π – x – y ---- [< sum of ⊿]

In ⊿OCB, [<]OCB = m = s(OB, r, z) ---- [sine law]

In ⊿BDC, n = y – m = θ + Ø – m ---- [ext < of ⊿]

In ⊿OBC, OC = t(OB, r, x + n) ---- [cosine law]